# Mysql counting join table OneToMany

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

**Task:**

```
id | title   | description | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Task1   | Descr1      | 
 2 | Task2   | Descr1      | 
 3 | Task2   | Descr1      | 
 4 | Task2   | Descr1      | 
 5 | Task2   | Descr1      |
```

**Message:**

```
id | task_id | message   | status |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1       | Message1  | HOLD
 2 | 1       | Message2  | OK
 3 | 1       | Message3  | ERROR
 4 | 1       | Message4  | ERROR
 5 | 2       | Message5  | HOLD
 6 | 2       | Message6  | OK
 7 | 2       | Message7  | OK
 8 | 2       | Message7  | OK
 9 | 3       | Message7  | OK
```

I want to show as here:

```
id | title   | description | count(HOLD) | count(OK) | count(ERROR)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Task1   | Descr1      | 1           | 1         | 2
 2 | Task2   | Descr1      | 1           | 3         | 0
 3 | Task2   | Descr1      | 0           | 1         | 0
 4 | Task2   | Descr1      | 0           | 0         | 0
 5 | Task2   | Descr1      | 0           | 0         | 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a selective aggregation baded on sum and CASE when

```
  select  task.id
    , task.title  
    , task.description
    , sum(case when Message.status = 1 then 1 else 0 end )  status1
    , sum(case when Message.status = 2  then 1 else 0 end )  status2
    , sum(case when Message.status = 3  then 1 else 0 end )  status3
from Task
INNER JOIN Message ON Task.id = Message.task_id
group by task.id
    , task.title  
    , task.description
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
SELECT task.id, task.title, task.description,

SUM(DECODE (status, 'HOLD',1,0 end)) AS "HOLD_COUNT"
SUM(DECODE (status, OK,1, 0 end)) AS "OK_COUNT"
SUM(DECODE (status, ERROR,1, 0 end ) AS "ERROUR_COUNT"

FROM task
JOIN Message ON Task.id = Message.task_id
group by task.id, task.title  , task.description
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct solution is:

```
select t.id, t.title, t.description,
       coalesce(sum( m.status = 'Hold' ), 0) as num_hold,
       coalesce(sum( m.status = 'OK' ), 0) as num_ok,
       coalesce(sum( m.status = 'Error' ), 0) as num_error
from task t left join
     message m
     on m.task_id = t.id
group by t.id, t.title, t.description;
```